# Can not get power button to work with display to display time as innerHTML?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently building a digital clock wow super easy yes i know. I guess what i want to be able to do is to click the powerButton to turn on the clock and then display the time inside the clockdisplay as innerHTML. I would like to use the variables from the setting time function and display them when the if statement executes. Can i get some help with this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style> 
        /*Google Fonts  */
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap');

        /*The Body the clock */
        #container {
            background-color: lime;
            /* border: 1px solid black; */
            border-radius: 15px;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
            left: 400px;
            top: 50px;
            width: 800px;
        }
        /**/
        #clock-display  {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid rgb(97, 97, 97);
            border-radius: 15px;
            font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
            font-size: 2em;
            height: 100px;
            line-height:100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            left: 30px;
            width: 400px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #clock-display:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0#00E4FF, 0 4px 8px 0 #C3FAFF;
        }
        #powerButton  {
            background-color: #E7E7E7;
            border: 2px solid #F7F7F7;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color:  white;
            position: absolute;
            height: 100px;
            line-height: 102px;
            top: 30px;
            left: 490px;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #powerButton:active {
            border: 2px solid #B8FDFF;
        }
        #power-icon {
            color: #FF0000;

            font-size: 2.7em;
        }
        #power-icon:hover {
            text-shadow: 2px 5px 5px#FF9898;
        }

        #alarm {
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid white;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left: 50px;
        }

        #text-box {
            border: 2px solid gray;
            height: 35px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left:175px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Basically a container that stores all the data -->
    <div id="container">

        <!-- The clock display where the time is to be displayed on.  -->
        <div id="clock-display"></div>

        <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->

        <!-- The HTML for the power button -->
        <div id="powerButton">
            <!-- the span that allows us to use css with the icon -->
            <span id="power-icon">
                <!-- the icon import from front-awesome ver 4.7.0 -->
                <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
        </div>

        <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->

        <!--Alarm container contains a label and input text box to retrieve your alarm time with audio.-->
        <div id="alarm-container"> 
        <label name="text-box">Alarm</label>
        <input type="text" id="text-box" name="text-box" placeholder="Enter Time Here"/>
        </div>

    </div>
        <!--  -->


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // global variables 
    var clockDisplay = document.getElementById("clock-display");
    var powerButton = document.getElementById("power-icon");
    var buttonON = document.getElementById("powerButton");

    console.log(clockDisplay); //exsists in the console in developer tools.

    function settingTime() {
        var x = setInterval(function () {
        var date = new Date();
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();

        });
        //return hours,minutes,seconds;
    }
    //button toggle algorithm i came up with that allows you to toggle the button with out built in function or jquery/vanilla api's
    function on_Off_Switch() {
        let numOfClick = 0;
        buttonON.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            numOfClick += 1;
            console.log(numOfClick);
            const randArr = ["#00F0FF","red"];
            if(numOfClick % 2 === 0) {

               powerButton.style.color = randArr[0];//red
               powerButton.style.textShadow = "1px 3px 3px #74F7FF, 2px 5px 5px white";


            } else {

                powerButton.style.color = randArr[1];//bluetooth bluetooth blue
                powerButton.style.textShadow = "1px 3px 3px #FF9898, 2px 5px 5px white";
                clockDisplay.innerHTML = "";                //where we turn off the audio to the radio if you decide to code it. 
            }
    });
    }

    function powerButtonToggle () {
        let toggle_int = 0;
            let z = setInterval(function() {
                toggle_int += 1;
                console.log(toggle_int);
                if(toggle_int % 2 === 0) {
                    $(powerButton).fadeOut(400, function() {
                    });
                }
                else if(toggle_int % 2 === 1) {
                    $(powerButton).fadeIn(400,function() {
                        console.log("this function is logging data");
                    });
                }
        },1000);
    }



    //main function 
    settingTime();
    on_Off_Switch();
    powerButtonToggle();


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should ask some more detailed, specific questions.  "Get some help" is too vague.  What, specifically, is not working as you wish?  for example.

Comment: in the program i am trying to write, I have 3 functions the first being how the current time is determined. That would be the settingTime() function. in the 2nd function im using a very small algorithm that toggles the button on and off plus give it some css.but what i really want to do is display the time from the first function so when i turn the clock on with the power button  the time is display as innerHTML for the clockDisplay variable. i feel like im not returning something right. I tried a couple approaches last night. what is wrong with my code sry for not being clear the first time.

Comment: Your clock will be out of sync after a while, because `setInterval` is basically "Don't do think after X milliseconds", where X is determined if there is something else going on. I would suggest to use `requestionForAnimationFrame`, which updates the clock every time the screen repaints. Check the time, since the last repaint, and update the screen accordingly.

Comment: Thx! @Rickard Elimää im actually in the process of rewritting this program. I just  figured out how to return what i wanted. Thank you so much for giving me insight. I actually ended creating a clockTime variable where i initialized with es6 formatted data. so basically rather than use clockTime = var1 + " : " + var2 + ":". i used something shorter like `${var1}:${var2)` which does the same thing. right now im tyring to write the function that updates the time since i returned it and move onto the powerButton which will display and updated time when the clock is turned on with the power button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.innerHTML` to rewrite the content inside of a certain tag.
For example,

```js
document.getElementById("clock-display").innerHTML = date + "; " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

will set the `clock-display` element to the date and time. An example is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            /*Google Fonts  */
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap');

            /*The Body the clock */
            #container {
                background-color: lime;
                /* border: 1px solid black; */
                border-radius: 15px;
                height: 300px;
                position: relative;
                left: 400px;
                top: 50px;
                width: 800px;
            }

            /**/
            #clock-display {
                background-color: white;
                border: 1px solid rgb(97, 97, 97);
                border-radius: 15px;
                font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
                font-size: 2em;
                height: 100px;
                line-height: 100px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 30px;
                left: 30px;
                width: 400px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #clock-display:hover {
                box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 0#00E4FF, 0 4px 8px 0 #C3FAFF;
            }

            #powerButton {
                background-color: #E7E7E7;
                border: 2px solid #F7F7F7;
                border-radius: 50%;
                color: white;
                position: absolute;
                height: 100px;
                line-height: 102px;
                top: 30px;
                left: 490px;
                width: 100px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #powerButton:active {
                border: 2px solid #B8FDFF;
            }

            #power-icon {
                color: #FF0000;

                font-size: 2.7em;
            }

            #power-icon:hover {
                text-shadow: 2px 5px 5px#FF9898;
            }

            #alarm {
                color: white;
                border: 1px solid white;
                height: 40px;
                width: 100px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 200px;
                left: 50px;
            }

            #text-box {
                border: 2px solid gray;
                height: 35px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 200px;
                left: 175px;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Basically a container that stores all the data -->
        <div id="container">

            <!-- The clock display where the time is to be displayed on.  -->
            <div id="clock-display"></div>

            <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->

            <!-- The HTML for the power button -->
            <div id="powerButton">
                <!-- the span that allows us to use css with the icon -->
                <span id="power-icon">
                    <!-- the icon import from front-awesome ver 4.7.0 -->
                    <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
            </div>

            <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->

            <!--Alarm container contains a label and input text box to retrieve your alarm time with audio.-->
            <div id="alarm-container">
                <label name="text-box">Alarm</label>
                <input type="text" id="text-box" name="text-box" placeholder="Enter Time Here" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--  -->


        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            // global variables 
            var clockDisplay = document.getElementById("clock-display");
            var powerButton = document.getElementById("power-icon");
            var buttonON = document.getElementById("powerButton");

            

            function settingTime() {
                var x = setInterval(function () {
                    var date = new Date();
                    var hours = date.getHours();
                    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                    var seconds = date.getSeconds();

                    document.getElementById("clock-display").innerHTML = date + "; " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

                });
            }
            //button toggle algorithm i came up with that allows you to toggle the button with out built in function or jquery/vanilla api's
            function on_Off_Switch() {
                let numOfClick = 0;
                buttonON.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    
                    numOfClick += 1;
                    
                    const randArr = ["#00F0FF", "red"];
                    if (numOfClick % 2 === 0) {

                        powerButton.style.color = randArr[0];//red
                        powerButton.style.textShadow = "1px 3px 3px #74F7FF, 2px 5px 5px white";


                    } else {

                        powerButton.style.color = randArr[1];//bluetooth bluetooth blue
                        powerButton.style.textShadow = "1px 3px 3px #FF9898, 2px 5px 5px white";
                        clockDisplay.innerHTML = "";                //where we turn off the audio to the radio if you decide to code it. 
                    }
                });
            }

            function powerButtonToggle() {
                let toggle_int = 0;
                let z = setInterval(function () {
                    toggle_int += 1;
                    
                    if (toggle_int % 2 === 0) {
                        $(powerButton).fadeOut(400, function () {
                        });
                    }
                    else if (toggle_int % 2 === 1) {
                        $(powerButton).fadeIn(400, function () {
                            
                        });
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }



            //main function 
            settingTime();
            on_Off_Switch();
            powerButtonToggle();


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow this is a wonderful example. i actually ended up solving this issue myself tonight. I really appreciate you in looking into this for me. I ended up using this method. 
***function first() {
            let date = new Date();
            let hours = date.getHours();
            let minutes = date.getMinutes();
            let seconds = date.getSeconds();
            let clockTime  = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
            return clockTime;
        }
        function second(y) {
            console.log(y);
        }
        var y = first();
        second(y);***